# Алгоритм выделения блока кода из позиции курсора?

Tags: алгоритм, синтаксический-анализ

Допустим, есть код следующий
`|` - каретка

```
function a () {
 let b = 20;
 |
}
```

В таком случае легко написать алгоритм выделения блока `{ let b = 20 }` просто пройти сначала направо или налево, найти положение открывающей/закрывающей скобки, сделать `counter` равный 1 и потом пойти в обратную сторону прибавляя или уменьшая счетчик в зависимости от того, какая скобка попадается в очередной раз и когда он будет 0 означает что блок закрылся.

Это так же сработает и для `{ | {} {} {} }`

Но это не будет работать для `{ {} | {} }`, как быть в этом случае? Есть ли вообще решение без разбиения всего кода на токены, выделение блоков, ast и прочее? Ну и как вообще лучше данную задачу решить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну почему же не сработает?

Открывающая скобка - +1, закрывающая - -1. Идем в вашем случае влево, получается последовательность (пишу значение после обработки каждой скобки по пути) -1, 0, +1. Все, стоп! +1 - найдена искомая открывающая скобка.

Идем вправо, имея +1. Далее - +2, +1, +2, +1, 0. Стоп! 0 - найдена закрывающая скобка.

Не сработает при наличии скобок в комментариях или строковых литералах, например. Тут нужно дополнительно разбираться...

Comment: Нет. 0 после -1 означает что блок закончен и результат будет `{ (результат) | {} }`
  
* круглыми скобками выделил для наглядности

Comment: `+1 - найдена искомая открывающая скобка.

` - мы точно не знаем тот ли это блок

Comment: Вы таки не поняли... Идя **влево**, мы ищем **единицу**. Только найдя ее, мы идем **вправо** и теперь ищем **нуль**. Так мы получим *первый охватывающий блок*.

Comment: Понял. Но чем отличается скобки в комментариях или строковых литералах от других? Те же скобки итерабельные

Comment: `{ s = "Hello! }"; }` - это блок? блок. А если стать, скажем, на `s` и работать - слева скобка найдена, а справа будет найдена скобка **в составе строки**. Ее считать нельзя, иначе получится, что блок - это `{ s = "Hello! }`, а разве это так?

Comment: Понял, спасибо!